# Set series index to another index with more levels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the index of a `Series` (`a1`) with an index (`ix`) that contains more levels than the series' original index.

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b'], 'x': [4, 5, 6]}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
>>> a
     x
a b   
1 b  4
2 b  5
3 b  6
>>> 
>>> a1 = a['x']
>>> a1
a  b
1  b    4
2  b    5
3  b    6
Name: x, dtype: int64

>>> ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([1, 2, 3], ['b', 'c'], [10, 20]), names=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> ix
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2, 3], [u'b', u'c'], [10, 20]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'a', u'b', u'c'])
>>> a.set_index(ix)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3164, in set_index
    frame.index = index
  File "python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3627, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas/_libs/properties.pyx", line 69, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 559, in _set_axis
    self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3074, in set_axis
    (old_len, new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 12 elements
```

as a result I'd expect the following Series:

```
a  b   c
1  b  10  4
2  b  10  5
3  b  10  6
1  c  10  nan   # [1, c] wasn't an index in a1
2  c  10  nan   # ...
3  c  10  nan   # ...
1  b  20  4     # [1, b] was an index of a1, so use that value
2  b  20  5     # ...
3  b  20  6     # ...
1  c  20  nan   # [1, c] wasn't an index in a1
2  c  20  nan   # ...
3  c  20  nan   # ...

# if there was an index in a1 that isn't in `ix`, it should be maintained with
# its value and the index should be augmented
```

How can I achieve this with Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html), but output is a bit different, because `MultiIndex` is sorted, what is obviously necessary if working later effectively - [source](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex):

> For `MultiIndex`-ed objects to be indexed and sliced effectively, they need to be sorted. As with any index, you can use sort_index().

```
a = a.reindex(ix)
print (a)
          x
a b c      
1 b 10  4.0
    20  4.0
  c 10  NaN
    20  NaN
2 b 10  5.0
    20  5.0
  c 10  NaN
    20  NaN
3 b 10  6.0
    20  6.0
  c 10  NaN
    20  NaN
```

Comment: @U9-Forward - No, because I am not developer. Developer know all ;)

Comment: @U9-Forward - hmmm, because I have time answering. Developers have no time, because working for bugs, improvements and new versions...

Comment: Okay, and Wes McKinney.

Comment: @orange - I test it in `0.24.2`, so in lower version should be difference

Comment: Interesting. The behaviour is indeed different. It changed from `0.22.0` to `0.23.0`. Time for an update, I guess... Thanks for your help @jezrael.

Comment: Another observation is that the order of the index levels is important: for instance `ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([10, 20], [1, 2, 3], ['b', 'c']), names=['c', 'b', 'a']); a.reindex(ix)` produces nan rows only.

Comment: Yet another observation: The target's series (`a`) has to have a `MultiIndex`, otherwise you'd get nan values only. Might be a bug in Pandas...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have an empty data frame which has three columns, and you are trying to assign a tweleve columns multi-index to it; If you create an empty data frame of four columns initially, the error will be gone:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 12)))    
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Or you can create empty data frame with the multi-index as follows:

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex(levels = [['first', 'second'], ['a', 'b']], labels = [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])    
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=multi_index)

df
#   first    second
#  a    b   a     b
```